# IP filtering for static web hosted endpoint through Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to host a website with only html,css,js files in the Azure cloud.
Seems like Azure Blob Static Website is a great option to host it for free if you have an Azure subscription.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

My question here is:
Is there any way to restrict the public IP addresses which can access the endpoint of the Azure Blob hosted Website?
Many of the Azure services provide this feature of IP filtering, but I did not find any way to do it for the above scenario.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

In the storage account, go to **Settings** → **Firewalls and Virtual Networks**

[image]

Check the radio **Selected Networks** and then configure the Firewall to allow selected IP address ranges.